# How to set height on canvas after filled some text?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm filling canvas with some dynamic texts in `ArrayList`. And I set the height as `length` of `ArrayList` like `ArrayList.length * 20` or something like that.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="272px" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

JS :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var myheight = 10;
for(var i = 0; mylist.length > i; i++){
     context.fillText("my text", 10, myheight);
     myheight += 10;
}
```

`loop` works fine, texts are filled.. and I'm trying to calculate the `canvas.height` after the `loop`.

When I set `canvas.height = myheight` and all filled texts are gone.. `canvas` gone blank.

How can I set `height` after `canvas` filled by texts dynamically?

Help me..
Thank you.. And sorry for bad English..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing window or canvas using `canvas.height = myheight` clears the canvas

you need to sava the content of canvas and redraw it again on the resized canvas

If you want to save the content of the canvas and redraw it,here is few options

1. Use `context.getImageData` to grab the whole canvas, resize the
   canvas, then use context.putImageData to redraw it at the new scale.
2. Create a new canvas with the updated size and call
   `context.drawImage(oldCanvas, ...)` to copy the old canvas onto the
   new one.
3. call `context.setScale(xscale, yscale)` and call whatever function you
   used to draw the canvas originally. Assuming you set up xscale and
   yscale correctly, it will automatically scale everything to the new
   size.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution to your problem is to calculate canvas height before drawing the text, because as you use canvas.height the canvas will be erased

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var myheight = 10;
for(var i = 0; 10 > i; i++){
    myheight += 10;
}

canvas.height = myheight;
myheight = 10;

for(var i = 0; 10 > i; i++){
   context.fillText("my text", 10, myheight);
   myheight += 10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/borja204/66dn06tq/1/